# ASP.NET OutputCache varyByParam does not work in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to cache some of my expensive to generate charts. So I did this in `Web.config`:

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
      <outputCacheProfiles>
          <!-- 4 hours : 60 sec x 60 min x 4 hour = 14400 sec -->
          <add name="ChartCacheProfile" duration="14400" varyByParam="none" />
      </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

And I added this in my `Controller`:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile="ChartCacheProfile")]
public ActionResult GenerateChart()
```

But this does not work..., the result is still not cached and the `Action` is being executed always. This can take up to 1 minutes to complete.

Please note that the url being called with different parameter every time. The parameter is unrelated to the chart being generated. That is why I put `varyByParam="none"`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Does not Work'? Further calls to the the Url are returned from Cache or entering the Action?

Comment: When you just refresh without changing any parameter, does hit still hit the Action?

Comment: When I refresh without changing the parameter, it does not hit the Action (it is caching!). When I move `varyByParam="none"` to `Controller` instead of `Web.config` the cache works.. I suspect this is a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect it is a bug indeed. What worked for me is to set `VaryByParam` explicitly in the `OutputCache` attribute:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile="ChartCacheProfile", VaryByParam="None")]
public ActionResult GenerateChart()
```

Comment: https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs#L23 could be the reason.

Comment: So is this a bug or by design?

Comment: I debugged the `OutputCacheAttribute.VaryByParam` and the value is always `*` despite of the value specified in web.config.

Answer (score 2):

I've got tired of this issue and having to set varyByParam for each action. So here's simple code for output cache attribute that gets varyByParam from web.config.
https://github.com/unconnected4/MvcOutputCacheFix/blob/master/ParameterizedOutputCacheAttribute.cs